# How do I vent Phazon in Metroid Prime 3 after...?

Tags: metroid-prime-3-corruption

Please note, I am trying to keep the question title and the first few lines of this question vague, because it's a major spoiler and if anyone else is like me and is just playing this game for the first time (yes, I'm way behind the times) I don't want to spoil it for them!

After I reach Phaaze and enter Hypermode permanently, I don't understand what to do to release Phazon, and as I continue to go deeper into the planet my Phazon bar just keeps filling up with more and more yellow, until I eventually die. It almost seems like firing charged shots and missiles *increases* the bar? I couldn't really tell from my one and only experience on Phaaze what to do to keep the yellow bar down.

How do I vent Phazon (and not die from corruption) in after reaching planet Phaaze?

Comment: There are certain enemies which can be used to vent phazon.Let me go dig up some more concrete information, and I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Okay. The creature you want to keep an eye out for are the [Phazon Puffers](http://metroid.wikia.com/wiki/Phazon_Puffer). They drain phazon from you to power their attack, reducing your corruption in the process. However, if they hit you with the attack, you wind up gaining more corruption than they first removed. A valid strategy then becomes to let the phazon puffers charge up, and then kill the creatures or dodge their attacks, reducing your phazon with each cycle.

You can also be proactive about this final segment by not traveling to Phaaze until you have the maximum amount of energy tanks. While it's not shown in terms of numbers, the more energy tanks you have, the larger your "effective" health, and thus the more corruption you are able to withstand.

On Phaaze, sometimes enemies drop "Anti-Phazon" pickups instead of the regular phazon health recovery you've been grabbing throughout the game, and absorbing these will reduce your corruption level.

Finally, using the overload (push forward) ability of the Hypergrapple (where applicable) will also reduce your corruption.

As you gathered yourself, your phazon corruption increases naturally both over time and as you take damage.

I could not, however, find any indication that firing your weapons increased *or* decreased your current phazon level.

Comment: In case anyone ever sees this question again, there is one final thing to take note of. The last obstacle before the final boss battle is a room with a Leviathan Infant. You rip off the sides of the husk, then shoot the organism within several dozen times to kill it. You're probably in a rush, since your corruption level keeps increasing, but after you blow the thing up, **stop and look around**; it leaves dozens of Anti-Phazon units behind. Draw them in with the charge beam, and you should be able to begin the final battle at 0% corruption.